# nginx + rails deployment: How to link root view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, server, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my rails application using nginx and passenger on an ubuntu server. When I go to the IP address in the browser I get the Welcome to nginx page and know that nginx is running. I can't figure out how to get this page (IP) to route to my app. I'm using Capistrano, so there a few more folders around my app.

The rails app Current dir is located at: `/home/[username]/apps/[appName]/`

The app is simple and the root view is an index page located at `apps/[appName]/current/app/views/static/index.html.erb`

My nginx.conf file includes:

```
...
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  [myURL - Not my IP];

    #charset koi8-r;                                                                                         
    charset utf-8;
    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;                                                                 

    root /[appname]/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
...
```

I tried to symlink with `ln -s /app/public app/views/static/index`

Answer (score 0):

In your NGINX configuration file, the `root` directive should be populated with the absolute path to your Rails public directory.  If I follow this correctly for your deployment, it would be:

```
root /home/[username]/apps/[appName]/current/public;
```

Of course, you will need to substitute in your username and appName.

For files other than static assets, Rails routing then handles processing user requests for pages and mapping them to the specified controller and view.  You should not need the symbolic link you describe (you should remove it).

Documentation for the root directive is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).